# Locally $C^k$ -function does imply globally $C^k$, right?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading Lawrence Perko book on ODEs, and on page 98, in the proof of theorem 1, he states something similar to:

> For every $(t,x_0) \in \Omega$, $\phi \in C^1(G)$, where
>   $G\subset \Omega$ is an open neighbourhood of $(t,x_0)$, then
>   $\phi\in C^1(\Omega)$.

$\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{1+n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is this correct? Can I extend this reasoning to $C^k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$? Intuitively, for continuity, I understand that this is true.

What about if the function were to be just differentiable, i.e. without continuous partial derivatives, then I'm not sure we could go from a local property to a global one... Or could we?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, the set-up is that you have some open domain $\Omega$, and a function $\phi:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ that satisfies the property that for every point $p \in\Omega$, there is an open neighborhood $G_p\subset\Omega$ such that $\phi:G_p\to\Bbb R$ is $C^1$.

This is exactly what it means for a function to be $C^1$ on all of $\Omega$. Often, this is phrased by saying something to the effect of "differentiability is a local property," and it is also true for $C^k$ for all $0\le k\le\infty$.

Comment: AOrtiz, thanks for the answer. I've edited the question. By the way, any good reference with a formal proof ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. This is often phrased as the definition of what it means for a function $\phi$ to belong to $C^1(\Omega)$: that for every point $p\in\Omega$, there is an open neighborhood $G_p\subset\Omega$ of $p$ such that $\phi$ restricted to $G_p$ is $C^1$. If you like, I think that John Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* covers smooth maps in some detail in chapter 2.